# How to get a DIV element's value, put them into array and use them later. JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to get the `data-league` values of all of those divs, and put them into an array.

[image]

What I want to do: Get all those values, save them, and then loop through them, and call a .click on those divs.

I don't know if there's an easier way to do this.

I guess it also has to loop through the divs where ID=128, and find the data-league values, right?

Honestly I'm completely stuck, so any help whatsoever would be appriciated.

Thank you.

**Extra info:** Basically the end result being, on click of a button, all those 'thumbnails' should open in a new tab. All tabs being different streams.
(See image)

[image]

Comment: `I guess it also has to loop through the divs where ID=128` This is not possible as `id` attributes must be unique within a document. You should use classes to group common elements instead.

Comment: you are using same ids for different elements that is wrong.

Comment: @Jai I agree with you on that, however I'm not the owner of the website. I'm simply editing it to my likings :)

Comment: In the example you provided the same id (128) has been used multiple times. This is not allowed. Iterating through the ids will not work

Comment: Check out the element (if you'd like) on "Vulcun.com". That's the website I'm trying write a script on.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it scritly on-topic, but I'm writing a bot, which could, on click of a button, open all the streams (thumbnails as seen on the image) on new tabs. But I can't get the script to 'click' on all of them, basically looping through them.

Comment: try $.each VideoPannel class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provided the same id (128) has been used multiple times. This is not allowed. Iterating through the ids will not work.

This means you have to look for another possibility. Getting all `div` elements with a certain class would be possible, like in the example:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('videoPanel');
```

Now you can iterate through this collection, extract the values for the attribute `data-league` and save them somewhere, for example in an array:

```
var dataLeagueValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    dataLeagueValues.push(divs[i].getAttribute('data-league'));
}
```

Now you have all values in the array `dataLeagueValues`. You can use them further in your script.

Comment: Thank you, let me try it out!

Comment: I used console.log(dataLeagueValues) to show the items saved, I'm getting empty arrays..- Is it because of the log command, or does it not actually work?? :/

Comment: @Paramone sorry, there was a typo. In the body of the for loop the closing bracket was missing. Now it is corrected. Pay attention on `('data-league'))` - the bracket should be closed twice - once for `getAttribute` and once for `push`.

Comment: Yes I noticed that aswell, and fixed that. But I still got empty arrays. I'll give it another try

Comment: Here it works. I tried that and it gives me `["1295", "1348", "1284", "1296", "1305", "1473", "1337", "1349", "1379", "1468", "1481", "1480", "1477"]`

Comment: How are you getting the results? I tried it with console.log(dataLeagueValues) showing empty arrays

Comment: I did that in the console, opened the page, pressed F12, entered all those commands above and got the result. How do you access the page from your script?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`$('[attribute]')`](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector to select elements with `data-league`, you can then use [`.each();`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop them.

The following example triggers a click on every element with a `data-league` attribute:

```
$('[data-league]').each(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

You could also make the selector more specific to only match these elements by their shared class name `videoPanel` e.g.

```
$('.videoPanel[data-league]').each(...);
```

Will target all elements with a class of `videoPanel` ***and*** an attribute `data-league`

To match what you need the full example would be:

```
var leagues = [];
$('.videoPanel[data-league]').each(function() {
    leagues.push($(this).attr('data-league'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet will your insert all `data-league` into an array.

```
var leagues=[];
$('.vedioPnnel').each(function() {
     var league = $(this).data('league');
     leagues.push(league);
});
console.log(leagues);
```

Comment: Okay, this somewhat works. It opens all the streams into new tabs, but what it does is..- it opens the data-channels. - What it should do, is 'click' on them. The site's url doesn't change. but the 'stream' shown does. 
Which I need

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use the javascript forEach function like in the folowing snippet.
Alternatively you can use:

document.querySelectorAll('[id="127"]');

or

document.querySelectorAll('[data-league]')

```js
function getAllDataLeague()
{
  var leagues = [];
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('div'), function (value, index, traversed) {
    var attrVal = value.getAttribute('data-league');
    if (attrVal) {
      leagues.push({'obj': value, 'data-league': attrVal});
    }
  });
  return leagues;
}


var eleFound = getAllDataLeague();


// print result in the html body
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>To access elements: eleFound[index]["data-league"]</p>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>To trigger the click event: eleFound[index]["obj"].click()</p>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Elements found:</p>';
for (var i = 0; i < eleFound.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>data-league:' + eleFound[i]["data-league"] + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<div class="game-listing-group">
    <div class="bold game-listing-name">CS:GO</div><div class="videoPanel vu-channel-tab" id="127" data-channel="https://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=m0e_tv" data-league="1284">
    <div class="video-thumbnail-con hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <img class="img-responsive video-thumbnail full-width" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_m0e_tv-320x180.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="videoPanelTextBg">
        <p class="indexVideoPanelTitle">Dragon lore giveaway NOW</p>
        <span class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount vu-league-gold pull-right" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount video-upcoming">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
        <span class="vu-league-start"></span>
    </div>

</div><div class="videoPanel vu-channel-tab" id="127" data-channel="https://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=freakazoid_tv" data-league="1296">
    <div class="video-thumbnail-con hidden-xs hidden-sm videoPanelTextBgActive">
        <img class="img-responsive video-thumbnail full-width" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_freakazoid_tv-320x180.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="videoPanelTextBg">
        <p class="indexVideoPanelTitle">BIRTHDAY IN 24HOURS! @c9freakazoid</p>
        <span class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount vu-league-gold pull-right" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount video-upcoming">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
        <span class="vu-league-start"></span>
    </div>

</div><div class="videoPanel vu-channel-tab" id="127" data-channel="https://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=gripex90" data-league="1301">
    <div class="video-thumbnail-con hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <img class="img-responsive video-thumbnail full-width" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_gripex90-320x180.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="videoPanelTextBg">
        <p class="indexVideoPanelTitle">Gripex - Most dedicated Lee sin! Top 50 Challenger</p>
        <span class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount vu-league-gold pull-right" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount video-upcoming">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
        <span class="vu-league-start"></span>
    </div>

</div><div class="videoPanel vu-channel-tab" id="127" data-channel="https://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=phantoml0rd" data-league="1346">
    <div class="video-thumbnail-con hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <img class="img-responsive video-thumbnail full-width" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_phantoml0rd-320x180.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="videoPanelTextBg">
        <p class="indexVideoPanelTitle">Level 400 Gambler LOL - Cycled over 3,000,000 in s</p>
        <span class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount vu-league-gold pull-right" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="indexVideoPanelGoldCount video-upcoming">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
        <span class="vu-league-start"></span>
    </div>

</div></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an infinite loop of falses :(

Comment: @Paramone, I fixed the bug and I propose you other two alternatives. I hope this can help you